# Replace does not seem to be working in this function?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get a textbox to change text in a div, and if square brackets are added I want a span to be added around the text to make the text green. Here is my code so far:

```js
function greenText() {
  var textAreaText = $('#textarea').val();
  var replacedText = textAreaText.replace("[", "<span style='color:green'>").replace("]", "</span>");
  $('#preview').html(replacedText);
}

$(function() {
  greenText();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview" style="height: 4em; background-color:#eee; padding:10px;"></div>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50" onchange="greenText();" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">
  At w3schools.com you will learn how to [make a website]. 
</textarea>
```

The `greenText` function works when the page loads, however when I am adding in brackets updating the `preview` div it prints the square brackets out to the page rather than the span tags. Does any one have any idea why the function isn't replacing the text?

Comment: Now that it is marked as duplicate I know what the issue is, the replace was only changing the first pair of brackets that it came across, rather than all of them in the string. I thought the issue lied with calling the function multiple times, or the HTML was being stripped out somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple replaces inside a string you need to use `RegEx`:

```js
function greenText() {
  var textAreaText = $('#textarea').val();
  var replacedText = textAreaText.replace(/\[/g, "<span style='color:green'>").replace(/\]/g, "</span>");
  $('#preview').html(replacedText);
}

$(function() {
  greenText();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview" style="height:400px; background-color:#eee; padding:40px;"></div>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50" onchange="greenText();" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">
  At w3schools.com you will learn how to [make a website]. 
</textarea>
```

Comment: This is a **very** commonly-posted question with a canonical duplicate. It doesn't need yet another answer.